# How to run the code in debug console instead of terminal

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I press F5 to debug the code.No output is shown in debug console.Instead, being shown in terminal.However,there's extra words that I want to delete.

For instance :
c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\java\java_vs_code>cd "c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\java\java_vs_code" && C:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.23.0\scripts\launcher.bat "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java" --enable-preview -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\f85dc17f73c63cbf830dece996d151d2\redhat.java\jdt_ws\java_vs_code_9d8b98fc\bin Hello
test

I have tried to view those similar questions.However, none of them can help the situation.

```
/**
 * Hello
 */
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

What my question is: Is there any solution to show output "test" only ?Help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try to add `"console": "internalConsole"` in your **launch.json** like :

```
"configurations": [
           {
             "type": "java",
             "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
             "request": "launch",
             "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
             "console": "internalConsole",
             "projectName": "my.app"
           }
         ]
```

then it will show in `Debug Console`

Comment: This helped. Shoutout for the answer.

Comment: "Property console is not allowed." ?